# nim language ,gintro demo with two columns in a listview / gtktreeview and sortable

Tags: gtk3, nim-lang

For nim language there is only one gui toolkit working for me and that is gintro.

The democode listview compiles and runs nice on my netbsd.
Source:
http://ssalewski.de/gintroreadme.html

But I need a listview(gtktreeview) with two columns, I looked into nim.gtk but can't figure out which "casts" I should spell.

The code in the demo program:

```nim
let gtype = typeFromName("gchararray")
let store = newListStore(N_COLUMNS, cast[pointer]( unsafeaddr gtype)) 
# cast due to bug in gtk.nim
```

Works nice for `N_COLUMNS=1` but not `N_COLUMNS:2`

Here is the relevant part in nim.gtk:

```nim
proc newListStore*(nColumns: int; types: GTypeArray): ListStore =
    let gobj = gtk_list_store_newv(int32(nColumns), types)
```

Second when I have multiple colums I would like to make it sortable by clicking on the header (like an excel table)

Comment: Do you use absolutely the same code for `N_COLUMNS=2`? Because it expects you to pass array of types containing 2 elements, not 1

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this:

```
let gtypes = [typeFromName("gchararray"), typeFromName("gchararray")] # Be sure to change the types to whatever you need.
let store = newListStore(N_COLUMNS, addr gtype[0]) # You shouldn't need this weird cast here.
```

Untested but should work. Feel free to join our Gitter/IRC if you need more help :)